# Poosh Woosh - How to make URLs in push note open in app

Tags: ios, pushwoosh

I am building a news website where one of the views is a webview of articles.
I had installed `push woosh` but when i send out notifications with URLs in them tapping the URL opens the web page in the native browser, is there any way i can set it so that the pages open in the webview in the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rich HTML Pages](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/features-guides/rich-html-pages/),

> Such pages can contain rich-formatted text, links and images.

Answer (score 1):

From GUI - yes, rich pages.

Also there is "remote_page" parameter in API. It's similar to "url" parameter, but it will be opened in webview.

For example:

```
{"request":{
    "auth":"TOKEN",
    "application":"APP-CODE",
    "notifications":[{
      "send_date":"now",
      "content":"test",
      "remote_page":"http://google.com"
    }]
}}
```

This url will be delivered as "r" parameter on your device. Be careful: max ios payload size is 255 bytes. And Pushwoosh will not short this url automatically. Do it by yourself if needed.